# iPhone - Disable Calling/Messaging Based on Bluetooth Signal

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bluetooth, arduino

I am using an Arduino Uno microprocessor in conjunction with a bluetooth shield. This is irrelevant. What is important is that I am sending a bluetooth signal form this device. I want to make an app for my phone to immediately turn off, be disabled, or at least have text messaging and calling disabled. Basically, I want to put this device in a car and when my phone gets near, calling and messaging is disabled. I am okay if I need to keep my app running in the background. I cannot find any examples on the web, so any suggestions are deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's security mode doesn't allow for this. You will need to jailbreak it. How to do that is left for the reader.

Then, I would read up on CoreTelephony private methods:

https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/IOS-7-Headers/tree/master/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework

Comment: But then how do apps that disable texting and calling while driving work?